# How to write test case for relational database operations using xunit

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, moq, xunit

I am using InMemoryDatabase for writing testcases, but when I want to test relational database operations(Insert/Update) I could not able to use InMemoryDatabase.
If I am using InMemoryDatabase  I am getting an error like

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Relational-specific methods can only be used when the context is using a relational database provider.'

Is there any way to test relational database operations(Insert/Update) without touching the development or production database?

This is the repository class which uses the relational db operations

```cs
public bool UpdateOrInsert(Model model, Details details = null)
{
    //_context is SqlDbContext
    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            if(details.Id > 0)
            {
                //Update details;
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                //Insert details;
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            
            if(model.Id > 0)
            {
                //Update model;
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                //Insert model;
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            transaction.Commit();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
         transaction.Rollback();
         throw;
        }
    }
}
```

How can we write unit test for this method without touching the real database? Is there any way?

The testcase I used to test this method throws the above error.

```cs
[Fact]
public void CheckTest()
{
    DbContextOptions<SqlDbContext> _options;
    _options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SqlDbContext>()
       .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "DbName1")
        .Options;
    
    using (var context = new SqlDbContext(_options))
    {
        context.Model.Add(_model);//_model= sample model object
        context.Details.Add(_details);//_details = sample details object
        context.SaveChanges();
        var cls = new ClassName();
        var result = cls.UpdateOrInsert(_model,_details);
        Assert.Assert.IsType<Bool>(result);
    }
}
```

If I use the following way to check, it will be possible to update the original database.

```cs
[Fact]
public void CheckTest()
{
    var connectionString = @"Data Source = *****; Initial Catalog = ******; uid = ****; Pwd = ******";
    DbContextOptions<SqlDbContext> _sqlOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SqlDbContext>()
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .ConfigureWarnings(x => x.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning))
    .Options;

    using (var context = new SqlDbContext(_sqlOptions))
    {
        var cls = new ClassName();
        var result = cls.UpdateOrInsert(_model,_details);
        Assert.Assert.IsType<Bool>(result);
    }
}
```

Do we have any other way to write test case for the method - UpdateOrInsert without touching the relational database?
Is it possible to test via InMemmoryDatabase?
Please help

Comment: Some of us try to only answer questions in areas where we have expertise. ;-) You might consider saving us a minute or two by not tagging an xunit question as nunit.

Comment: Why did you tagged your question with nunit? Also why did you tagged it with unit-testing if you have a problem with integration testing?

Comment: Could you please indicate which line throws this `InvalidOperationException`?

Comment: @PeterCsala in the line _context.Database.BeginTransaction()
if we use inmemmory it will throw the error
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction.TransactionIgnoredWarning: Transactions are not supported by the in-memory store

Comment: Any idea to proceed the testcase